# If Column view header is empty, the header does not fill the full size in IE

Tags: css, xpages

The problem is hard do describe without a screenshot...

I've styled the column view headers of views in xpages using this css just to get an gradient in all browsers:

```
.xspPanelViewColumnHeader {
       background: #58a8cd; /* Old browsers */
       /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
       background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzU4YThjZCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzBjODNiMiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUxJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzBmNmM5NSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMxMjdkYWEiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
       background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #58a8cd 0%, #0c83b2 50%, #0f6c95 51%, #127daa 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
       background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#58a8cd), color-stop(50%,#0c83b2), color-stop(51%,#0f6c95), color-stop(100%,#127daa)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
       background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #58a8cd 0%,#0c83b2 50%,#0f6c95 51%,#127daa  100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
       background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #58a8cd 0%,#0c83b2 50%,#0f6c95 51%,#127daa 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
       background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #58a8cd 0%,#0c83b2 50%,#0f6c95 51%,#127daa 100%); /* IE10+ */
       background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #58a8cd 0%,#0c83b2 50%,#0f6c95 51%,#127daa 100%); /* W3C */
       background-position: left top;
       color: #FFFFFF;
       padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
       font-weight: bold;
 }
```

Works fine so far. But if the column view header does not have a label there's a problem with the gradient in IE9 (not in Firefox).

In IE9 the gradient does not fill the full size of the header - i can see two blocks (one horizontal and on vertical) but both only a few pixels wide. But the rest of the column header stays white.

As soon as I enter a label (and even if it is only a ".") the header will be displayed as usual (full height and full width with the gradient).

This way works:

```
<xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader1" value="."></xp:viewColumnHeader>
```

This doesn't:

```
<xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader1"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
```

So the question is (if anybody could follow my description): How can I edit the css to prevent the column header to shrink with no defined label?

Comment: Could you maybe call a client side javascript and check to see if the innerhtml is null then add a non breaking space.  I know that seems like a pain just to get IE to behave.

Comment: But even if I add a non breaking space the problem persists. It only worked when I add a letter or any other character